# Azure MSI support for VM (Classic)

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

Is there a plan for support for MSI on VM of type "classic"?
I can't seem to find the "Configuration"-tab as shown in the screenshot on this guide?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-qs-configure-portal-windows-vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no plans to support MSI on classic VMs, since they are not under Azure Resource Manager. MSI depends on Azure Resource Manager.

-Arturo

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've made a workaround for these machines by using the "AzureServicesAuthConnectionString" environment variable until the servers are migrated... Thanks for the fast reply